# Eloquent : Creating additional row with alias to the result set

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Suppose I have a user table with columns `id, name, age`

With a normal get query `User::get()`, I get all results with those column's value.

But instead of just getting the `id, name, age` columns, 
is it possible if I add another column, perhaps a column with an alias of `future_age` with a value of `age + 1`.

**The above result could be achieved in SQL like so:**

```
SELECT res.*, (SELECT sum(res.age+1) from users where id = res.id) as future_age from users as res
```

I've thought about looping through the result and creating new key. but I think this would make the query execution time slow when the data is lengthy.

Is it possible to create the `future_age` key/column (I don't know the term hehe) directly on the query?

**Currently, this is my query:**

```
$user = User::get();

$new_res = []
if($user->count() > 0) {
    foreach ($user as $u) {
        $u['future_age'] = $u->age + 1
        $new_res[] = $u;
    }
}
```

The query works tho, but I don't think this is good if I have a large set of data.

Comment: Your question is not clear. what is your eloquent query?

Comment: @Raskul I edited the question, hope I made it clear.

Comment: probably you want to add a new record to users, am I right?

Comment: @Raskul exactly